# Inject HTML from file in Astro

Tags: astrojs

Is it possible to inject HTML from file in Astro?

Something like `set:html="..."` but instead of string, I want to pass file path, for example `/icon.svg`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import both SVGs and HTML and then use them in Astro components. HTML supports importing and using as a component. SVGs can be imported with a `?raw` suffix and need to be used with `set:html`.

```
---
import HTMLSnippet from '../snippet.html';
import Icon from '../icon.svg?raw';
---

<HTMLSnippet />
<Fragment set:html={Icon} />
```